# SQL query for selecting maximum from 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, max

I got a question in my homework for SQL about selecting the maximum values from the same table that have different class "Letters"

For example:

```
ID    Student     Group    Avg(value)
-------------------------------------
1     stud1        A        9
2     stud2        A        9.5
3     stud3        B        8
4     stud4        B        8.5
```

What my query should do, is to show stud2 and stud4.The maximum from their respective groups.

I managed to do it in the end, but it took a lot of characters so I thought that maybe there's a shorter way to do. Any ideas? I used to first search the id or the stud that has max avg(value) from group A, intersecting with the id of the stud that has max avg(value) from B and then putting everything into one big select and then using those intersected IDs into another query that requested to show some different things about those IDs. But as I said, it looked far too long and thought that maybe there's an shorter way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I renamed group to grp and avg to avg_val as those are reserved keywords):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
inner join (
    select grp, max(avg_val) avg_val
    from your_table
    group by grp
) t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp
and t1.avg_val = t2.avg_val;
```

It finds maximum avg value per group and joins it with original table to get the corresponding students.

Please note that if there are multiple students with same avg as the max value of the that group, all of those students will be returned.

Comment: i forgot to specify that ID,Student and Group are from one table named "Studs" and Avg(value) from another table named "Grades" also, when i said those numbers from avg(value), it's by using the function avg on the grades that those students have..So stud1 from A has 6 grades that make the avg(value) of 9.

Comment: The solution above is the approach you can follow to solve this kind of problem. Instead of the table name your_table, you can put a join of the two table instead as a subquery maybe.

Comment: it's too long, but i will try the join within another select and hopefully make it shorter..the query you putted above gave me some idea of how to make it shorter